# NetBeans doesn't recognize the latest JavaFX version

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I'm working on a project that requires the latest JavaFX version. There are certain classes that NetBeans is not recognizing. For instance the Alert class, is giving me a "Cannot find symbol" warning. 
I'm getting this following message at run time:

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.65 by JavaFX     runtime of version 8.0.0
```

I've installed the latest Java version today. Although, it's not showing under the path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

I'm using OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Then netbeans is not using the latest version you installed. It should install under the folder you mentioned. Where did it go?

Comment: When I installed it, the installer didn't show me the path it downloaded. So I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect installed Java versions on your Mac with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Alternatively, `find / -name javac -print | less` might help, too, but it will emit quite a few "permission denied"s, and a few false positives (name of dirs in documentation folders).

Does NetBeans find your new Java version, when you open the Java Platform Manager (Tools, Java Platform in the menu bar) and click the Add platform-button?

EDIT:

At java.com the "consumer version" (the jre) can be downloaded. Currently it gets installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`. The JDK can be downloaded directly from Oracle.

Comment: I followed your command: /usr/libexec/java_home -V. When I checked the last modified date (with: ls -l) it shows it as being created on April 6 2014: drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Apr  6  2014 jdk1.8.0.jdk. So I must assume that's not the Java I downloaded two days ago.

Comment: Do you still have the url in your browser history? What I mean, do you remember which file you downloaded?

Comment: I downloaded Java from here: https://www.java.com/en/download/
I also reinstalled NetBeans SE from here yesterday (It comes with JavaFX): https://netbeans.org/downloads/
A colleague has the same exact problem, also running OS X.

Comment: Try downloading the JDK from [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). At java.com you get the jre. After you have downloaded the new version, you may have to add a new Java Platform in NetBeans and assign that to your project.